# Using Macros for Automatic Formatting in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

We're trying to create something that will allow us to copy lines from a technical document which is unformatted and in font X, and paste them into a form or into something that will produce it in a specific format into font Y. Some sections need to have 1.25" tabbing, whereas others just need .5" tabbing. We're ok with pasting individual chunks, as long as we can hit a "submit" button, or something that allows the other end to be completely formatted on its own.

Right now, we're doing everything manually, and it's taking up to 20 - 25 minutes a document and the formatting has to be proofed. We'd like to automate almost everything so all it requires is a copy and paste and a quick glance.

We've looked into Microsoft Word Macro's, but don't know if that's the right solution? Any thoughts?